# Installing Cucumber in a new Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

1. I create a new Rails application,
2. add `cucumber-rails` gem to a `Gemfile`,
3. run `bundle install` and
4. `rails generate cucumber:install`.

I would like to have `web_steps.rb`, `paths.rb` generated. But those files are not generated. Here is the bash output:

```
create  config/cucumber.yml
create  script/cucumber
chmod  script/cucumber
create  features/step_definitions
create  features/support
create  features/support/env.rb
exist  lib/tasks
create  lib/tasks/cucumber.rake
gsub  config/database.yml
gsub  config/database.yml
force  config/database.yml
```

What do I need to change to generate all the Cucumber files needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those files are no more generated with newer versions of cucumber:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/issues/174